# java(1150,0x10df2d000) malloc: *** error for object 0x10df9b020: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I'm working on a java project and keep getting this error message on my console when I try running my jUnit tests... it starts running and then randomly stops with this error.

I'm running running on

- MacOSX v10.7.5
- java version "1.7.0_25"
- Eclipse Juno Service Release 2

I've tried running the disk repair thing because i've found that solution elsewhere but didn't do anything usefull for me.

thanks

Comment: Unless you've got some JNI you're using or have a 3rd-party API that uses JNI, this indicates a JVM bug and should be reported.

Comment: I also get this error in OS X and Eclipse, may be an OS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar errors when trying to start up tomcat with a similar setup of mac, java, and eclipse.  My solution ended up being updating java to the latest update.

was running jdk1.7.0_11

now running jdk1.7.0_79

and the errors stopped.